# swing download not works in windows xp

Tags: java, swing

I have a sample code to download some data (pdf,gif and mp3) from a web and its a swing application.It works perfectly in Windows 7 but  not working in Windows xp.

My code is

```
 public static Float downloadFile(String targetUrl,File filePath)
        {
            try
            {

                Integer count=0;
                URL url = new URL(targetUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                connection.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
                Thread.sleep(100);
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                Thread.sleep(100);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                byte data[] = new byte[input.available()];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
                {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 2.5f;
            }  
    }
```

It enters into the infinite while loop by setting the code to 0

Comment: Do both systems have the same JRE installed? What is Thread.sleep for?

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is "input.available()" when you initialize your buffer?  If it happens to be "0" at that moment, you'd be sad.

One solution is to use a fixed-length buffer (e.g. 8192).